# how to check if information provided is in a different schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, one-to-many, mongoose-schema, mern

On sign up page, I want to check if the email, first name and last name entered by the user is in the organization schema or not, if it's in the database then create a new user

my user schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    organization: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Organization'
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "First name is required"],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Last name is required"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      validate: {
        validator: (val) => /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)?$/.test(val),
        message: "Please enter a valid email",
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
      minlength: [8, "Password must be 8 characters or longer"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

organization schema:

```
const OrganizationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orgname: {
        type: String
    },
    domain: {
        type: String
    },
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User' }
    ],
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
})
```

the answer might be easy to some but I am new to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem in your conception.

How are you supposed to find user's firstname and lastname in the organisation entity?

The relation here is the following :

- an Organization can have multiple users
- a User can have an Organization

If you want your organization to be used a a "filter" for the signup process, you could do the following:

- have an Organization schema that holds a whitelist of domain and (firstname / lastname) -> you can have a collection but it would duplicate a lot of information,
- have a User schema that is linked to Organization like you did in your question.

You can optimize Organization schema by splitting it (to prevent info duplication for the orgname and domain) :

- Schema Organization (name, domain)
- Schema Whitelist (link to organization, firstname, lastname)
- Schema User (link to organization)

Tell me if you need me to clarify something.

Comment: Thank you for this, what query to use to access it and check?

Comment: Just before inserting your user on signup, you can query organization to check if the domain exist `const organization_found = org.find({domain: 'the domain entered'})`. If it exists, you can then check if the whitelist contains your user `const whitelist_found = whitelist.find({organization: organization_found._id, firstname: 'firstname_entered', lastname:'lastname_entered'});`

Comment: Thank you so much! one more question, i get the domain entered with req.body.domain right? is there another way?

Comment: Depends on the framework you're using. For example if you're using nest, I would recommand creating a DTO and then access if with the following annotation : `@Body(ValidationPipe) signUpDto: SignUpDto,`